# The source of any delphi component is unavailable in my IDE

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-2010

I'm using delphi 2010, and in order to create components i'd like to see the source of delphi components such TEdit, TButton... But the problem is this option is unavailable in my IDE, the type of any added component is written in black (and not in blue so i can see the source). So how can i get this option?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Sometimes the ide can't find it. Can you find it on the disk?

Comment: @David I'm curious if the `Debug DCUs` option is available in trial or starter editions. That might also help OP find the source, if it really is there.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using either a trial version or starter edition of Delphi. The source is deliberately not available. You would have to acquire / pay for a higher edition of Delphi, such as Pro, Enterprise, Ultimate, or Architect.

If you wish to study how components / controls work, find a popular third-party one. For example, I've been experimenting with [Chrome Tabs](https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs) lately.

Comment: I'm using delphi 2010 Architect. Anyway thanks for reply, but is there any other way to get the source of delphi components? I tried to google it but no interesting results.

Comment: @Emily Can you find the source files on your computer? For example, my XE7 source is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\source\rtl\win`. Are you running an unactivated trial?  Unfortunately, it's not legal for us to give you the source by any other means.

Comment: Yes, I can find the source files, and i'm running an activated trial. Anyway thanks again for your responses.